# Can't detach from tmux session while process is running

Tags: bash, ssh, tmux

I am logging in to a remote linux machine via ssh, and then I start a batch process in tmux.
However, I can't detach from the current tmux session using Ctrl + b + d.
So, for starting another tmux session I have to open another terminal, ssh connect and restart the session in the new terminal.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Edit: When I try to detach by hitting ctrl+b+d there is no reaction

Thanks
Roland

Comment: What stops you from detaching from the `tmux` session? What happens when you try? Please update your question.

Comment: (1) The default is not `Ctrl + b + d`, it's `Ctrl + b`, release, then `d`. (2) Are you sure `Ctrl + b` is the prefix? It's the default prefix, one can customize it.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski you're absolutely right.
In fact, I forgot that, and didn't find it again in the web. I just found "ctrl+b+d".
Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

In fact, I forgot to hit "ctrl + b", release, and then d. I did it without releasing. Thanks to @KamilMaciorowski!
Seems to be not well explained in the web.

Comment: God I'm an idiot, I was hitting control+b, letting b go (but not control), and hitting d. So of course it wasn't working. Thanks!